# Get drawn rect of UIImageView image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is there a simple way to get the visible / drawn rect of a UIImageView's image? The rect needs to be correct for any chosen contentMode and should take masksToBounds into account.

Example1: 100x100 UIImageView with a 200x200 image, masksToBounds = YES and contentMode = BottomLeft should return x=0, y=0 (or 100 depending on the coordinate system), width=100, height=100.

Example2: 100x100 UIImageView with a 200x200 image, masksToBounds = YES and contentMode = Center should return x=50, y=50, width=100, height=100.

Or do I have to calculate it myself depending on the contentMode and masksToBounds settings of the UIImageView? I thought properties on the CALayer of the UIImageView could help me with that, but so far I wasn't able to get the right values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of research, I'm pretty sure, it's not possible to get that rect. You need to calculate it manually.

You can either make use of the view's contentMode property or use the layer's contentGravity property to determine the way the image was positioned inside the imageView.

Comment: AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect() only allows you to calculate the AspectFit case, but not dynamically depending on the image view's settings, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @wolfrevo that's because AspectFit is the only case in which you should need to calculate the drawn image size. In any other case, you can use either the bounds of the UIImageView itself, or the native size of the image.